# how to emulate .transition from D3 in Angular or React

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, transition

All:

I wonder if I want to do data visualization using React JSX or Angular template to replace D3 DOM manipulation (such as .enter().append() .exit().remove()), how can I implement the animation transition like .transition().duration() in either of them?

For example, I build a line chart, in d3 after I change data set and generate new path, there is animation for those line to transform

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem with using D3.js in React is that both want control of the DOM, right?

D3 wants to directly select elements, add elements or remove elements based on the data being used, and add attributes to those elements.

React likes to have everything represented in it's virtual DOM and doesn't like any changes to the actual DOM without it's consent.

After some research, some people try utilizing some of React's different life cycle methods to instigate specific D3 methods at different points in a components life. For example, one approach wants you to return false to ComponentWillUpdate and use functional side-effects to run the D3 code on the actual DOM. While this works for some cases, it's still an improper use of React, and you're losing out on the benefits of passing state to any children components that component may be rendering.

I would suggest researching some of these approaches of how people have tried to tackle the issue, to see the root of the problem.

Also, feel free to try out this library my friends and I made that allows you to plug in your existing D3 code as is, and returns React components, and handles transitions, animations, timers, etc.

http://react-d3-library.github.io/

Always looking for more feedback!